# Create a single IAM user to access only specific S3 bucket

Tags: json, linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I have many S3 buckets in my AWS account. But now I created an IAM user and a new S3 bucket, I would like to give this user the ability to access the new S3 bucket using a client like CyberDuck.

I tried to create so many policies. But after that this user getting permission to list all my other buckets also. How can I give access to listing and writing access to a single S3 bucket?

Comment: The permission to view a list of bucket names cannot be limited to only returning one bucket. Either they can list _all_ the bucket names, or _none_ of the bucket names. You can, however, restrict permissions _within_ a bucket on a per-bucket basis.

Answer (score 10):

First you create a Policy to allow access to a single S3 bucket (IAM -> Policies -> Create Policy). You can use AWS Policy Generator (http://awspolicygen.s3.amazonaws.com/policygen.html), it should look something like this:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "Stmt1528735049406",
      "Action": [
        "s3:DeleteObject",
        "s3:GetObject",
        "s3:HeadBucket",
        "s3:ListBucket",
        "s3:ListObjects",
        "s3:PutObject"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::YOURBUCKETNAME"
    }
  ]
}
```

Save the policy and note the name you gave to it, then go to IAM -> Users and select the desired user. In the permissions tab, click 'Add permissions', then select 'Attach existing policies directly' near the top. Find your policy by its name, tick its checkbox and complete the process.

Comment: Thank you for giving the reply. But unfortunately, when I using the s3 through the client I got "Access denied error"

Comment: Try: `"Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::YOURBUCKETNAME", "arn:aws:s3:::YOURBUCKETNAME/*"]

Comment: When accessing S3 with a client program, you must use API access key. Select the user in IAM and use 'Create access key' in the 'Security credentials' tab.

Answer (score 3):

Per this ( https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/writing-iam-policies-grant-access-to-user-specific-folders-in-an-amazon-s3-bucket/ )

they’ll need to be able to at least list all the buckets. But other than that, this also provides an example policy, which I just used last night for my own account, so I can confirm that it works.

**Update**
Okay, I've tested and confirmed using CyberDuck that the following policy (customized to your environment of course) will prevent users from viewing all root buckets, and only allow them access to the bucket you specify:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowAllInBucket",
            "Action": [
                "s3:*"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-for-single-user"
        }
    ]
}
```

Just make sure that when you specify the path in CyberDuck, that you enter it as: `bucket-for-single-user.s3.amazonaws.com`.

Also, **only START** unrestricted like that, just to make sure it's working for you (since access appears to be an issue). After that, **apply restrictions**, you know...least privilege and all.

Comment: @thisAronMdev thank you.But again listing all my other buckets also for this IAM user

Comment: @SruthinKumarTK sure, but once listed, can they view the contents of the other buckets or just the contents of the one you've granted them access to?

Comment: @SruthinKumarTK okay, updated my answer with a working policy, based off of the information in the URL I originally linked. I've tested it so I know that it works the way you want (for me at least).

Comment: I have updated my policy like this.when opening the Cyber-Duck, I getting access denied message

Comment: 1) did you specify the bucket name as BUCKETNAME.s3.amazonaws.com in CyberDuck, 2) when creating the policy, did you make sure to attach it either to the user, or group/role the user is associated with (as well as detach any other policies for now), 3) have you confirmed the access key ID and secret access key are correct and valid for the user? If yes to all of the above, then I can’t think of anything else that could be wrong, but someone else might.

Comment: Thank you @thisAaronMdev for the reply. Finally, I create my own policy. I have posted here.

Answer (score 2):

According to [Cyberduck Help / Howto / Amazon S3](https://trac.cyberduck.io/wiki/help/en/howto/s3), it supports directly entering the Bucket name, as `<bucketname>.s3.amazonaws.com`. If this is possible with the client you are using, you don't need `s3:ListAllMyBuckets` permissions.

**Action**s should be grouped by the **Resource**s that they can parse
(**Conditions** are also potentially different per **Action**).

This IAM policy will allow full control of all the content (aka *in the bucket*)
without controlling of the S3 bucket subresources (aka *of the bucket*):

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "BucketOperations",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:ListBucket*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::<bucketname>"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "ObjectOperations",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
               "s3:AbortMultipartUpload",
               "s3:ListMultipartUploads",
               "s3:DeleteObject*",
               "s3:GetObject*",
               "s3:PutObject*"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::<bucketname>/*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "DenyAllOthers",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "NotResource": [
               "arn:aws:s3:::<bucketname>",
               "arn:aws:s3:::<bucketname>/*"
            ]
        }
    ] 
}
```

If you aren't specifically trying to lock the IAM user out of every
possible public S3 bucket, you can leave the "DenyAllOthers" `Sid` off,
without granting additional permissions to the users.

FYI, the AWS `ReadOnlyAccess` policy automatically gives `s3:*` to
anything it's attached to. I recommend `ViewOnlyAccess` (which will
unfortunately grant `s3:ListAllMyBuckets` without the `DenyAllOthers`).

Answer (score 0):

Create my own policy and working for me. The IAM user can just list all bucket. But cant do anything on another bucket. The user can only get access to the specific bucket with reading, write, delete files privileges.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "<EXAMPLE_SID>",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:ListBucket",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::<MYBUCKET>"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "<EXAMPLE_SID>",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
            "Resource": "*"
        },  {
            "Sid": "<EXAMPLE_SID>",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Action": "s3:ListBucket",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::<MYotherBUCKET>"
        },  {
            "Sid": "<EXAMPLE_SID>",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:DeleteObject"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::<MYBUCKET>/*"
        }

    ] 
}
```

Then add this policy also to this user. This policy will restrict all type of operation to listed other s3 bucket.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "<EXAMPLE_SID>",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutAnalyticsConfiguration",
                "s3:GetObjectVersionTagging",
                "s3:CreateBucket",
                "s3:ReplicateObject",
                "s3:GetObjectAcl",
                "s3:DeleteBucketWebsite",
                "s3:PutLifecycleConfiguration",
                "s3:GetObjectVersionAcl",
                "s3:PutBucketAcl",
                "s3:PutObjectTagging",
                "s3:DeleteObject",
                "s3:GetIpConfiguration",
                "s3:DeleteObjectTagging",
                "s3:GetBucketWebsite",
                "s3:PutReplicationConfiguration",
                "s3:DeleteObjectVersionTagging",
                "s3:GetBucketNotification",
                "s3:PutBucketCORS",
                "s3:DeleteBucketPolicy",
                "s3:GetReplicationConfiguration",
                "s3:ListMultipartUploadParts",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutBucketNotification",
                "s3:PutBucketLogging",
                "s3:PutObjectVersionAcl",
                "s3:GetAnalyticsConfiguration",
                "s3:GetObjectVersionForReplication",
                "s3:GetLifecycleConfiguration",
                "s3:ListBucketByTags",
                "s3:GetInventoryConfiguration",
                "s3:GetBucketTagging",
                "s3:PutAccelerateConfiguration",
                "s3:DeleteObjectVersion",
                "s3:GetBucketLogging",
                "s3:ListBucketVersions",
                "s3:ReplicateTags",
                "s3:RestoreObject",
                "s3:GetAccelerateConfiguration",
                "s3:GetBucketPolicy",
                "s3:PutEncryptionConfiguration",
                "s3:GetEncryptionConfiguration",
                "s3:GetObjectVersionTorrent",
                "s3:AbortMultipartUpload",
                "s3:PutBucketTagging",
                "s3:GetBucketRequestPayment",
                "s3:GetObjectTagging",
                "s3:GetMetricsConfiguration",
                "s3:DeleteBucket",
                "s3:PutBucketVersioning",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl",
                "s3:ListBucketMultipartUploads",
                "s3:PutMetricsConfiguration",
                "s3:PutObjectVersionTagging",
                "s3:GetBucketVersioning",
                "s3:GetBucketAcl",
                "s3:PutInventoryConfiguration",
                "s3:PutIpConfiguration",
                "s3:GetObjectTorrent",
                "s3:ObjectOwnerOverrideToBucketOwner",
                "s3:PutBucketWebsite",
                "s3:PutBucketRequestPayment",
                "s3:GetBucketCORS",
                "s3:PutBucketPolicy",
                "s3:GetBucketLocation",
                "s3:ReplicateDelete",
                "s3:GetObjectVersion"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::<MYotherBUCKET>/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::<MYotherBUCKET>"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Glad it's working for you, though, is there a reason you're using two different policies instead of just simply doing ` "Effect": "Deny","Action": "s3:*","Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::<MYotherBUCKET>"` since that appears to be what you're trying to accomplish? If it's working _the way you way_, then call it good, but being a little more concise couldn't hurt.

Comment: When I using like ` "Effect": "Deny","Action": "s3:*","Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::<MYotherBUCKET>"` I got access denied error.So i create two policies

Answer (score 0):

I was recently able to get this to work using Amazon's [documentation](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-console-access-certain-bucket/). The key for me was to point the IAM User to the **specific bucket NOT the S3 console**. Per the documentation, "Warning: After you change these permissions, the **user gets an Access Denied error when they access the main Amazon S3 console**. The main console link is similar to the following:

https://s3.console.aws.amazon.com/s3/home

Instead, the user must access the bucket using **a direct console link to the bucket,** similar to the following:

https://s3.console.aws.amazon.com/s3/buckets/awsexamplebucket/"

My policy is below:

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "Stmt1589486662000",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "s3:*"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::AWSEXAMPLEBUCKET",
            "arn:aws:s3:::AWSEXAMPLEBUCKET/*"
        ]
    }
]
}
```