# What's the right way to write an amazon s3 bucket policy?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, policy

I'm trying to upload an image from a .NET webservice to an amazon s3 bucket.

By using this public policy on the bucket i can do that:

> ```
> {
>     "Id": "Policyxxxxxxxx",
>     "Version": "yyyy-MM-dd",
>     "Statement": [
>         {
>             "Sid": "xxxxxxxxxx",
>             "Action": [
>                 "s3:GetObject",
>                 "s3:PutObject"
>             ],
>             "Effect": "Allow",
>             "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::(bucketName)/*",
>             "Principal": "*"
>         }
>     ] }
> ```

But when i try to give access only to my user/credentials like this:

> ```
> {
>     "Id": "Policyxxxxxxxx",
>     "Version": "yyyy-MM-dd",
>     "Statement": [
>         {
>             "Sid": "xxxxxxxxxx",
>             "Action": [
>                 "s3:GetObject",
>                 "s3:PutObject"
>             ],
>             "Effect": "Allow",
>             "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::(bucketName)/*",
>             "Principal": {
>                 "AWS": [
>                     "arn:aws:iam::(accountID):user/(userName)"
>                 ]
>             }
>         }
>     ]
> }
> ```

i get "Accces Denied".

So what im doing wrong with the policy?

Comment: There could be two things, either it's not the IAM user/role which is making PUTObject or you don't have permission on the IAM user/role policy.

Comment: The user gets identified by the Access key ID + Secret access key used? 
Just created a new pair does not grant me accces (root user)

Comment: What commands are being issued by the .NET webservice? It might be trying commands other than `GetObject` and `PutObject` (eg `ListBucket`).

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to grant access to an Amazon S3 bucket to a particular IAM User, you should **put the policy on the IAM User itself** rather than using a bucket policy.

For example, see: [Create a single IAM user to access only specific S3 bucket](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50802536/174777)